# Implement a dictionary by using direct addressing on a huge array

Tags: algorithms, hash

For the following question from Introduction to Algorithms book, "We wish to implement a dictionary by using direct addressing on a huge array. At the start, the array entries may contain garbage, and initializing the entire array is impractical because of its size. Describe a scheme for implementing a direct address dictionary on a huge array. Each stored object should use $ O(1)$ space; the operations SEARCH, INSERT, and DELETE should take $O(1)$ time each; and the initialization of the data structure should take $O(1)$ time. (**Hint**: Use an additional
stack, whose size is the number of keys actually stored in the dictionary, to help determine whether a given entry in the huge array is valid or not.)"

**Problem**: can you please help explaining the wording of the question in your own words? No solution is needed.

Comment: Are you sure about the additional stack? To me it doesn't sound as an efficient data structure for supporting lookups in a hash table.

Comment: @Chaos. Thanks for reply. Yes, this is from the book!

Comment: Ok, i see what they did there.

Comment: Glad you liked my answer! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"We wish to implement a dictionary by means of an hashing function that maps all its possible inputs to a huge but finite set of natural numbers of size $k$. The function is implemented by values of an array witnessing the presence/lack of any element. The array is expensive to setup, so we ask that the algorithm does not clear it. (It is used for holding pointers to present elements.) Describe an algorithm for granting, constant time operations, constant space usage for items storage (pointers to objects) and constant initialisation time. ( Hint. Employ and additional stack for avoiding false positives on insert/removal and lookup operations.)"

False positives are due to the presence of garbage.
Possibly the most nebulous part is the usage of the stack. Since it is bounded in size (at most $k$), you will have to scan from it at most $k$ elements. Since it's size is bounded you can have lookups in O($k$) and that's constant time.

Comment: How is $O(k)$ constant time? nobody said anything about the size of $k$ being bounded.

Comment: Direct hashing requires $k$ to be known and constant and as such bounded. It can be set at compile time (actual constant) o before the algorithm is run (configuration value). What matters is that it does not change during execution.

Comment: What is $k$ in your definition? I thought you meant it is the number of items in the map

Comment: It is the size of the range of the hash function, also the size of the array. Well, it depends on how you actually definite the hash function but it at least must be the size of the array.

Comment: The size of the array is said to be "huge" and thus it is impractical to go through the entire array. Did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @nirshahar. You are correct about this. This is unbounded problem from the context, but Chaos gives nice implementation. I am just trying to approach the working in the question as it's a little tricky

Comment: According to me the point is that the stack can be filled with dummy values that do not require to be scanned. If you did actually scan them, then it would take O($k$). Since you can avoid them it must that less than O($k$).

Comment: @Chaos. This is very expensive if you have very large number.

Comment: Well, the algorithm must be correct. If the hash is full all values are taken and the stack contains a 'huge" amount of additional information that could have been kept in the array only. So, having additional data structures will require to pay higher costs. You could have 2 stacks, one for inserted items, one for removed. Still you have to scan them to avoid the completely full case. I would also like to remind that direct hashing is practical for small $k$s, so this exercise is just for students. It does not give rise to practical algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another hint: how would you find whether an element is valid in $O(1)$ in this auxiliary stack? Try to somehow "connect" the index at the original huge array, to the place in the stack that says that this element is indeed valid. Don't be afraid to use another auxiliary array for this!

Comment: Initializing the auxiliary stack won't be $O(1)$. Is it?

Comment: So, the basic idea is a stack holding a pointer to an element in the dictionary. If we want to make sure that the element is valid, we first map the key a slot in the dictionary, then the slot holds the stack index holding a pointer to this current slot in dictionary. This is confusing?

Comment: If we have very large stack, we don't want the compiler to go over every single item and set it to Nil. This is one application I guess as I understood elsewhere from @user21820.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami Without clearing the data in it, there is a way to do this. since its a stack - we know exactly which elements are valid: all elements with an index less than the current number of items in the stack.

Comment: @Avra I think you got it right - something along the lines that you wrote in the first comment should work. If something wasn't initialized then it will either map to outside the stack size (and hence is invalid) or will map to an element within the stack, which will point back to a *different* value, hence we know it is not really valid.

Comment: @nirshahar Won't we have to initialize the connection pointers also? They should be "null" initially for every index in the huge array.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami we don't need to. There is a way to do it without this initialization. If you want, I can post it as a full answer (but it doesn't look like the OP wanted a full answer anyways)

Comment: https://tildesites.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall09/Homeworks/old/rest/H6-sol.pdf

Comment: @Nayuki this is precisely what I had in mind :)